# How to process SAML response and get the attributes in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, saml, codeigniter-4

I am new to CodeIgniter(Using version 4) and working on SSO integration for my application. From the Login Controller I am calling the idp URL and authentication is working fine. I need to get the attributes from the SAML response. Please tell me how to access the response and get the attributes.

Code snippet of my controller class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Login extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
    return redirect()->to("https://example.com/idp/startSSO.ping?Param=value");

    // how to retrieve response and get attributes here?
    }

}
```

On redirect to https://example.com/idp/startSSO.ping?Param=value it will show a login form. On entering the correct details it is redirecting to the homepage properly. But after successful login I am not able to process/get  the SAML response which contains the logged in user details.

Comment: You need to use CurlRequest library:
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/curlrequest.html

Comment: @silentwasd Tried it now. but the redirect is not working properly. How can i redirect and get the SAML response here?   `class Login extends BaseController
{
 public function index()
 {

 $client = \Config\Services::curlrequest();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://example.com/idp/startSSO.ping?Param=value', [
    'verify' => false,
 'allow_redirects' => true
]);
echo $response->getBody();

}`